# php + sqllite3: sometimes (minority) ERROR: Warning: SQLite3::exec(): near... syntax error

Tags: php, sqlite

I have the following Problem: I have an array with about 10200 entries.
I have a loop, where I write an entry from the Array into Variables and than I INSERT the Values from the Variables into a new and clean SQLite DB.
The problem is: there is a 0.05% chance, that it won't work, so 100000 entries are in the dB and 200 are missing, or not complete. :(

```
//write the datas from the array into Variables:
foreach ($followers as $follower) {
    $usernameId = $follower->getUsernameId();
    $username = $follower->getUsername();
    $full_name = $follower->getFullName();
    $ProfilPicUrl = $follower->getProfilePicUrl();
    $is_private = $follower->isPrivate();
    $time = time();

    $sql_insert_users =<<<EOF
      INSERT INTO users (
        user_id,
        username,
        full_name,
        profile_picture,
        is_private,
        is_follower,
        followed_on,
        updated_on)

   VALUES ('$usernameId', '$username', '$full_name', '$ProfilPicUrl', '$is_private', 1, '$time', '$time');
EOF;

//write all in dB:
$ret = $db->exec($sql_insert_users);
 if(!$ret){
    echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    echo "\n". $usernameId. " - ". $username. "\n"; //show me the ID and username, if it fails!

} else {
   //echo "Records created successfully\n";
}
}
```

The errorlog looks like this:

```
Warning: SQLite3::exec(): near "m": syntax error in /Users/.../Sql_db_test.php on line 316
near "m": syntax error
1837386174 - madleen_official_

Warning: SQLite3::exec(): near "MD": syntax error in /Users/.../Sql_db_test.php on line 316
near "MD": syntax error
1402422812 - itz_finnest
```

And since i have a correct output of the variables (eg. 1402422812 - itz_finnest), i really don't know, what's the problem.

**EDIT 1**

as suggested from @Alex K, i am now using prepared. That helped. i now don't get any error messages, but there is still a Problem, that a few hundred entries in the coloumn "username" are simply "0" instaed of an actual name. I used echo, to see, if there is something wrong with the array, but it shows me an actual name and never a "0" like it is written in the database.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO REGISTRY (name, value) VALUES (:name, :value)");
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
$stmt->bindParam(':value', $value);

// eine Zeile einfügen
$name = 'one';
$value = 1;
$stmt->execute();

// eine weitere Zeile mit anderen Werten einfügen
$name = 'two';
$value = 2;
$stmt->execute();
```

This is the form I am using, but in a loop.

Comment: Use a prepared statement: http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.prepare.php